# How to get data from big json in go

Tags: json, go

I have that json and now i need to get that field "textValue": [
"BigFoot Inc."
]

All that I have now been able to get is data from an array of custom data. But I can't get data from a specific field. I tried to get the data, but everything is very sad, I will be glad for your help

JSON:

```
  "id": 759,
  "author": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Gogi Na Vole",
  "completedOn": "Never",
  "custom_fields": [
    {
      "id": 86,
      "name": "property_86",
      "label": "Type of Question",
      "value": [
        "90"
      ],
      "textValue": [
        "Other"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 69,
      "name": "property_69",
      "label": "Client",
      "value": [
        "82"
      ],
      "textValue": [
        "BigFoot Inc."
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

MyCode:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

var body = []byte(`JSON HERE
`)

type TiketData struct {
    Struct here
}

func main() {
var data TiketData

    json_err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    if json_err != nil {
        fmt.Println(json_err)
    }

    for _, customFields := range data.CustomFields {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%#v", customFields))
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of that code? Also, does the JSON format is predefined or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to define `struct type` for your JSON. I used auto-generated `struct type` but you can divide into multiple ones. Then, just apply the same steps for unmarshalling and access the variable. I hope it will solve your problem.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var j = `{
  "id": 759,
  "author": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Gogi Na Vole",
    "completedOn": "Never",
    "custom_fields": [
      {
        "id": 86,
        "name": "property_86",
        "label": "Type of Question",
        "value": [
          "90"
        ],
        "textValue": [
          "Other"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 69,
        "name": "property_69",
        "label": "Client",
        "value": [
          "82"
        ],
        "textValue": [
          "BigFoot Inc."
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}`

type Data struct {
    Id     int `json:"id"`
    Author struct {
        Id           int    `json:"id"`
        Name         string `json:"name"`
        CompletedOn  string `json:"completedOn"`
        CustomFields []struct {
            Id        int      `json:"id"`
            Name      string   `json:"name"`
            Label     string   `json:"label"`
            Value     []string `json:"value"`
            TextValue []string `json:"textValue"`
        } `json:"custom_fields"`
    } `json:"author"`
}

func main() {
    var data *Data
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    textVal := data.Author.CustomFields[1].TextValue
    fmt.Println(textVal)
}
```

Output will be:

```
[BigFoot Inc.]
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/apkEWkbmjoh)

Comment: What if there are more custom fields? and the client is no longer 1 item?

Comment: id 69 is always the same value

Comment: JSON has `custom_fields` and it gets array. So, if you want to access one of the array elements, you need to use array indexing. To know in which index is the client in array, you can traverse the array with `for` loop and checks the id or label at each step.